# SQLite: Add up integer tables based on shared indicators

Tags: sqlite, join, addition, insert-update

I am aggregating numbers from different sqlite databases into a single output database table.

I need to add up integer columns `i1,i2,i3` in the output table based on three indicating columns `a,b,c` that tell me which rows to update:

```
ATTACH DATABASE "out.db" AS output;
INSERT INTO output.rows(a,b,c,i1,i2,i3)
SELECT DISTINCT "some_value", b, c, 0, 0, 0 FROM main.rows
ON CONFLICT IGNORE;

#THE FOLLOWING LINES MIGHT SHOW WHAT I MEAN...
UPDATE output.rows SET i1=i1+i1_,i2=i2+i2_, i3=i3+i3_
WHERE a="some_value" AND b=b_ and c=c_
SELECT i1_, i2_, i3_, b_, c_ FROM main.rows;
```

I do not want to type in all the combinations of `a,b,c`. As you can see, `a` does not come from `main` but from external information (the filename).

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of SQLite that support UPSERT, the following seems to work:

```
ATTACH DATABASE "$out.db" AS output;

INSERT INTO output.rows(a,b,c,i1,i2,i3)
SELECT "some_value", b, c, i1, i2, i3 FROM main.rows WHERE true
ON CONFLICT (a,b,c) DO UPDATE SET i1=i1+i1, i2=i2+i2, i3=i3+i3;
```

In my case, the columns `i1,i2,i3` coming from `main` actually had a different name (say `I1,I2,I3`) than their counterpart in `output`, therefore the `UPDATE` was clearer (`i1=i1+I1`). I failed to reference as `main.rows.i1` inside the `UPDATE` statement. If you know how to solve that ambiguity, please comment.